# How to append a number to a html div class via programatically

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a div with a class name .I want to append a number programatically to the class name.
my div

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

I need to add count++ value to append to the class name test.Then the class should be test1

here is my code

```
int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
<div class="test+count++"></div>

}
```

but it showing test+1
can any one help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
string str="";
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
 str+="<div class='test'>"+Convert.ToString(i)+"</div>";

}
```

Comment: do the cast `Convert.ToString(count)` is required?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int count=0;string str="";
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
str+="<div class='test"+Convert.ToString(count++)+"'></div>";

}
```